# Javascipt emulates private variables but javascript are already private because of scope?

Tags: javascript, closures

I've been studying javascript just now and i'm currently in closures. It is said that closure emulates private variables. But aren't variables only accessible on their own scope making them private by default? Given this example

```
function manageSalary () {
    let salary = 0;
    function updateSalary(amount) {
        salary += amount;
    }
    return {
        raise: function(amount) {
            updateSalary(amount);
        },
        deduct: function(amount) {
            updateSalary(amount);
        },
        current: function () {return salary}
    }
};
```

How exactly does closure makes the salary variable private in this example? Isn't salary already private since you cant access it outside this manageSalary? What I understood from this example rather is that closure emulates private methods instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tackling your questions *slightly* out of order:

> Isn't salary already private since you cant access it outside this manageSalary?

Yes.

> How exactly does closure makes the salary variable private in this example?

The closures don't *make* `salary` private. As you said, it's already private. The closures take advantage of the fact `salary` is private but they (the closures) aren't. The return value of `manageSalary` is an object with those closures on it as (effectively) methods. The methods have access to `salary`, but nothing *else* has access to it.

Comment: Okay so i guess i understood it correctly then. The only thing that confuses me is that why do most examples associate closures with private variables. Is there some scenarios I don't yet that can best show how closures emulate private variables in javascript?

Comment: @KariasBolster - I don't understand the question. But note that you've said "private *variables*". Most places that talk about doing this are talking about emulating private *properties*. For instance: `function Counter() { var value = 0; return {current: function() { return value; }, increment: function() { return ++value; } }` Instances created via `new Counter` effectively have a private property called `value`. (Of course, this will all [soon be moot](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) as true private fields are coming to JS.)

Comment: Sorry I guess what I meant to ask is why is there a need to emulate private variables when variables are already private. But I guess that would be depending on what one is trying to achieve and that would be out of topic. Anyways thank you for the clearing things up for me.

Comment: @KariasBolster - They aren't emulating private *variables*. They're emulating private *properties*.